# Paypal Button for Google Chrome Extension Manifest Version 3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, paypal, content-security-policy, manifest.json

I'm trying to get a paypal smart button to load through my Google Chrome Extension.

Here is the page with the button working in JSFiddle.
NOTE that I have a newer JS fiddle below in the question for review after this (this is merely shown to show you the progress so far and where I started).
https://jsfiddle.net/ZQVerse/k2e6nh5r/182/

https://jsfiddle.net/741ntrqj/ <-- Newest JSFiddle for quick reference

This page also works when I run under my localhost.

[image]

When I attempt to load my buy page from the google chrome extension however I get the following visual errors and javascript console errors.

[image]

[image]

The error is that it refuses to the load the script because it violates the content security policy directive "script-src 'self'"

So I did a test... and if you add this as a meta tag to the HTML it can work when you run it as a file without everything disapearing.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-hashes' fonts.googleapis.com; object-src 'self' https://www.paypal.com 'sha256-U2vsCzUQ797LcHkgCQJsOSAJxY/+LTdJONJ+wacPXrI='; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.paypal.com">
```

I believe this worked because the paypal button was being loaded inline.  I have since changed my code to the jsfiddle below now.

https://jsfiddle.net/741ntrqj/

So the improvements in this JSFiddle is that I now load the JS and CSS as separate files and not inline removing the need for unsafe-inline content-security-policy which Google Chrome Extension apparently does not allow anymore.

That said I still get the same error when it attempts to load my buy page via the chrome extention.

I should note that the page is being created from a button press on my popup page which sends a message to the background service worker.  This is the code that opens up the page in a new tab.  The page looks functionally correct except for the **paypal button not being there!**

```
if (request.buy != null) {
   chrome.tabs.create({
       url: 'buy.html'
   });
}
```

**How do I get the paypal button to work and show up from within a Google Chrome extension using manifest 3?**

I have tried modifying the manifest to include this:

```
"content_security_policy": {
        "extension_pages": "default-src 'self';script-src 'self'"
    }
```

Doing this didn't work and the buy page then looked even stranger with the promotional **video background image disappearing for some reason? Also the google fonts didn't load either**

[image]

Google doesn't appear to allow the 'unsafe-inline' or 'unsafe-hash' so I am at a loss for how to make this work.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Manifest.json

```
{
    "name" : "Trading View Input Optimizer",
    "description" : "Automatically experiment with different inputs to discover which inputs deliver the optimal results with an optional easy to see heat map",
    "version" : "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "icons": {
        "16": "./images/icon-16.png",
        "32": "./images/icon-32.png",
        "48": "./images/icon-48.png",
        "128": "./images/icon-128.png"
    },
    "background":{
        "service_worker": "./background.js"
    },
    "action":{
        "default_popup": "./popup.html",
        "default_icons": {
            "16": "./images/icon-16.png",
            "32": "./images/icon-32.png",
            "48": "./images/icon-48.png",
            "128": "./images/icon-128.png" 
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "scripting"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://tradingview.com/*",
        "https://*.paypal.com/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://*.tradingview.com/*"],
            "css": ["trading-view.css"],
            "js": ["./js/jquery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js","./src/inject/tradingview-content-script.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You'll need to try something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67439012/chrome-extension-manifest-v3-content-security-policy for the external script, https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AWDr6hAeYCdOR8sgXJbPVumh7apMnSlhhPOkZa6_YGKW5GGW6vYsJvzSl42D&enable-funding=venmo&currency=USD

Comment: I've tried this for the past 4 hours with no luck so far, can you give me an example how to do it?

Comment: ManifestV3 disallows external scripts by design. Copy it into extension and load locally.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have created a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76821201/2725810) asking to explain how to go about implementing your suggestion. Your answer will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> So I did a test... and if you add this as a meta tag to the HTML it can work when you run it as a file without everything disapearing.

Unfortunately `jsfiddle.net` does not allow you to add custom meta tags. If you look at the contents of the jsfiddle's iframe of your test, there will be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
... jsfiddle's head content ...
</head>
<body>
<body>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
    ... your head content with <meta CSP> ...
    </head>
   <body>
   ... content of page ...
</body>
</html>
```

Meta tag Content-Security-Policy is not applied if it's placed not in right `<head>` section, therefore you CSP just ignored.

> 

Manifest V3 [does not allow](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#remotely-hosted-code) to use remote scripts. Have a look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65769339/content-security-policy-in-manifest-v3-for-facebook-page-plugin/12865944?noredirect=1#comment116284448_3959875) comment for the similar issue of Manifest V3 for the script of Facebook SDK, maybe this will help you.

Comment: I got it to work using manifest version 2 so far, I can post that answer shortly.  When I was refering to the meta tag, that was on my local file host not jsfiddle

Comment: Yes, manifest V2 (MV2) allows to include third-party scripts and using `'unsafe-inline'`, this is a known workaround. The $1000 question is how long Google will support MV2. Meta tag on local host will works indeed, despite minor errors in CSP you provided (`'sha256-value'` is not supported in `object-src` directive; `script-src` contains `'unsafe-hashes'` token is used without `'sha256-value'`).