# How to bring PayPal script into the extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, paypal, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

As has been clarified in many posts, we are not allowed to reference an external script in the Manifest V3 Chrome extension. One [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69502371/paypal-button-for-google-chrome-extension-manifest-version-3#comment122850259_69502371) is to copy the script into the extension.

I am not sure how to implement this suggestion for the Paypal script mentioned in this error:

[image]

To begin with, how do I download the script? I tried doing "Save as..." from the browser, but got "File not found". I tried `wget https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js`, but got the 400 response.

Comment: Wouldn't you need a UMD version? I don't think you can reference raw JSX inside of the Chrome browser?